# "Show more comments" in flag queue and on MSO should not have the `a:visited` style

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools, design

I noticed that posts in the mod queue seemed to be getting a blue "show more comments" link.

It seems that they are inheriting the `a:visited{color: #1f6c82;}` style instead of the `.comments-link{color: #888;}` style.

[image]

That doesn't seem right. And the color makes me twitchy.

Update: and now it is affecting MSO as well:

[image]

<sup>Jin, please don't [bludgeon me to death with a giant color palette!](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)</sup>

Comment: I wondered what that was.